# Writing a shell in c, question about ($?) value

Tags: c, shell, unix

I am working on writing a shell in c. One of my buildin I have to implement is 'echo', I wonder how do I get the value of $? if my command were such as 'ls filename ; echo $?'. In this case, I have to use fork to create a new process and use execv to run binary ls in the system, after execute ls, how do I know the exit status of ls?

Comment: That would be returned by various `wait` functions that you'd have to have called anyway to find out if the process has exited

Comment: Oh this sounds like a class. One book I found extremely good is Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment. I don't know if that's still a textbook or if you were assigned something similar. But if you expect to be doing a lot of work involving UNIX you might want that book.

Comment: Yes, I am learning by working on this project. my question is solved.  Thanks for all the answering and Zan 's book recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting for a particular PID you can wait for any PID in a few ways. You can install a signal handler for SIGCHLD and in the handler call `wait(&status)` and it will return the PID and store the process exit status.

Or you can install a signal handler using `sigaction` and the `SA_SIGINFO` flag. Then the signal handler will have an extended signature which includes a `siginfo_t*` parameter and for a SIG_CHLD signal it will contain the PID and the status.

Or instead of a signal handler, you can use `wait` or `waitpid` (with a PID of -1) to wait for any process and it will return the PID of whichever one exited. Assuming your program is tracking how many children it forked, you'd handle that process exit and go back to waiting for whatever is next.

Waiting for any exit is important if your shell has job control which allows running and tracking the state of any number of background processes.

Answer (score 1):

After the call to `fork`, the parent process needs to wait for the child process to complete. It most likely does this using `waitpid`. When it calls `waitpid`, it can pass a pointer a memory location where it wants to get the "status information" of the child process, including its exit status. See [the `waitpid` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) for details about how to interpret the "status information".